# A direct proof that this space is normal

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I recently came across a question asking to show that by adding a single point to the Moore plane one can obtain a normal space. Instead of just going for the one-point compactification, I constructed a different space, which I can show is normal by showing it is paracompact and Hausdorff. However I would like a more direct proof of its normality.

Let $\mathbb M = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y \geq 0 \}$, and consider the subsets $\mathbb M_0 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb M : y = 0 \}$ and $\mathbb M_1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb M : y > 0 \}$. For each $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^2$ and $r > 0$ let $B_r ( \mathbf x )$ be the usual open disc of radius $r$ centered at $\mathbf x$. The *Moore plane* is the space obtained by defining the following sets to be the basic open neighborhoods of each $\mathbf x = (x,y) \in \mathbb M$:

- If $\mathbf x \in \mathbb M_1$, the basic open neighborhoods of $\mathbf x$ are the $B_r ( \mathbf x ) \cap \mathbb M$ for $r > 0$.
- If $\mathbf x \in \mathbb M_0$, the basic open neighborhoods of $\mathbf x$ are the $D_r ( \mathbf x ) := \{ \mathbf x \} \cup B_r ( (x,r) )$ for $r > 0$.

My space $X = \mathbf M \cup \{ \star \}$ is given the topology where

- Every open subset of $\mathbb M$ is open in $X$.
- The basic open neighborhoods of $\star$ are of the form $\{ \star \} \cup \bigcup \{ D_{r ( \mathbf x )} ( \mathbf x ) : \mathbf x \in Z \}$ where $Z$ is a cofinite subset of $\mathbb M_0$, and $r( \mathbf x ) > 0$ for each $\mathbf x \in Z$.

Can someone provide an outline of a direct proof (using either the "disjoint closed sets" or "open set containing a closed set" definition) that this space is normal?

---

I will add a fairly complete outline of one part of the proof of normality. (Thanks to Ire Shaw for helping me focus on this case at least.)

Suppose that $F,E$ are disjoints closed subsets of $X$, neither of which contains $\star$. It follows that both $F \cap \mathbb M_0$ and $E \cap \mathbb M_0$ are finite, so we may enumerate them, respectfully, as $$\{ \mathbf x_1 = (x_1,0) , \ldots , \mathbf x_n = (x_n,0) \}; \quad \{ \mathbf u_1 = (u_1,0) , \ldots , \mathbf u_m = (u_m,0) \}.$$

For $i \leq n$ there is an $r^\prime_i > 0$ such that $D_{r^\prime_i} ( \mathbf x_i ) \cap E = \emptyset$. Simiarly, for $j \leq m$ there is an $s^\prime_j > 0$ such that $D_{s^\prime_j} ( \mathbf u_j ) \cap F = \emptyset$.

For $i \leq n$ define $$r_i = \min \left( \left\{ \frac{r^\prime_i}2 \right\} \cup \left\{ \frac{(x_i-u_j)^2}{4s^\prime_j} : j \leq m \right\} \right)$$
For $j \leq m$ define $$s_j = \min \left( \left\{ \frac{s^\prime_j}2 \right\} \cup \left\{ \frac{(x_i-u_j)^2}{4r^\prime_i} : i \leq n \right\} \right)$$
One can show that for $i \leq n$ and $j \leq m$ we have $D_{r_i} ( \mathbf x_i ) \cap D_{s_j} ( \mathbf u_j ) = \emptyset$.

For $\mathbf{x} \in F \cap \mathbb M_1$ there is an $r^\prime(\mathbf x)$ such that $B_{r^\prime(\mathbf x)} ( \mathbf x ) \cap E = \emptyset$. It can be shown that for $j \leq m$ since $\mathbf x \notin D_{s^\prime_j} ( \mathbf u_j )$, then $\mathbf x \notin \overline{ D_{s_j} ( \mathbf u_j ) }$, and so there is an $r_j ( \mathbf x ) > 0$ such that $B_{r_j} ( \mathbf x ) \cap D_{s_j} ( \mathbf u_j ) = \emptyset$. Set $$r ( \mathbf x ) = \min \left( \left\{ \frac{r^\prime ( \mathbf x )}{2} \right\} \cup \left\{ r_i ( \mathbf x ) , \ldots , r_m ( \mathbf x ) \right\} \right).$$

Do the same for $\mathbf u \in E \cap \mathbb M_1$ to get an $s ( \mathbf u ) > 0$ such that

- $B_{2 \cdot s ( \mathbf u )} ( \mathbf u ) \cap F = \emptyset$;
- $B_{s ( \mathbf u ) } ( \mathbf u ) \cap D_{r_i} ( \mathbf x_i ) = \emptyset$ for $i \leq n$.

Set

- $U = \bigcup_{i \leq n} D_{r_i} ( \mathbf x_i ) \cup \bigcup_{\mathbf x \in F \cap \mathbb M_1} B_{r ( \mathbf x )} ( \mathbf x )$
- $V = \bigcup_{j \leq m} D_{s_j} ( \mathbf u_j ) \cup \bigcup_{\mathbf u \in E \cap \mathbb M_1} B_{s ( \mathbf u )} ( \mathbf u )$

Then $F \subseteq U$, $E \subseteq V$, and $U \cap B = \emptyset$.

---

The real difficulty appears to be just showing regularity at $\star$. That is, if $F \subseteq X$ is closed and does not contain $\star$, then there are open sets $U,V$ such that $\star \in U$, $F \subseteq V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

I can achieve this if $F \subseteq \mathbb M_0$, however I cannot come to grips on how to handle points in $F \cap \mathbb M_1$.

Comment: The definition of open neighborhoods when  $\mathbf x\in \mathbb M_0$ does seem a bit confusing to me. Do you mean $D_r(\mathbf x)=\{\mathbf x\}\cup B_r(\mathbf x)$ ? . In this case, since $\mathbf x\in B_r(\mathbf x)$ does  $D_r(\mathbf x)= B_r(\mathbf x)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Choose any pair of close sets $A,B$.

If both $A$ and $B$ do not contain the point $⋆$, then $A^c$, $B^c$ are both open neighborhoods of $⋆$. Hence $A$, $B$ contains only finitely points of $\mathbb{M}_0$.

Note that the restriction of $X$ to the upper halfplane $\mathbb{M}_1$ is equiped with the normal topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.Then if we write $A=A_0\cup A_1$ where $A_i=A\cap M_i$,$i=1,2$, and similarily $B=B_0\cup B_1$, easily $A_1,B_1$ can be seperated by two open sets $V_1,U_1$.

Since $A_0$, $B_0$ contains only finitely points, write $A_0= \{ a_1,\dots a_n\}$ and $B_0=\{ b_0 \dots b_m \}$. There exist a $R>0$ such that for any $r<R$ we have:
$$\cup D_r(a_i) \bigcap \cup D_r(b_i)=\emptyset$$

If for all $r$ the equality $(\cup D_r(a_i)) \cap U_1 \not = \emptyset$ holds, it will follows that there exist at least a $a_k$ belongs to $B$. Similarily the argument goes for $A$.

Then for a proper $r$ we find that the sets $V = V_1 \cup (\cup D_r(a_i))$ and $U= U_1 \cup (\cup D_r(b_i))$ are the desired ones.

If there exist a set in $A$ and $B$ which contains $*$, says $*\in A$. Since $A\cap B =\emptyset$, $* \not\in B$, that is $B^c$ is a open neighborhood of $*$, then $B$ contains only finitely points of $\mathbb{M}_0$.

Write $B_0 = \{ b_1,\dots,b_k \}$. First we want to find open neighbourhoods of $A_0 =  A \cap \mathbb{M}_0$ and $B_0 = B \cap \mathbb{M}_0$ in $\mathbb{M}_0$. In fact the vital part of this is actually how to deal with points in $A_0$ that being very close to points in $B_0$. Here is the detail:

First choose a r such that $U_0 = \cup D_r(b_i)$ has covered $B_0$. For every point $a$ in $A_0$, let $\delta_{a,n} = \frac {d_{a,n}^2}{4r}$, where $d_{a,n}$ is the distance between $a$ and $b_n$. So let 
$$\delta_a = \mathrm{min}\{ \frac {\mathrm{min}_n(\delta_{a,n}) }{2}, r \}$$
(to prevent the radium getting to $\infty$), $V_0=\{*\} \cup (\cup_{a\in A_0}D_{\delta_a}(a))$ is now by definition a open neighbourhood of $A_0$ with $V_0 \cap U_0 = \emptyset$.

The remaining is all about $\mathbb{M}_1$. I think from now on it's really "similar"  to the above case :)

...Well, by definition all points in $A_0$ is isolated point for $B$, then for any $a$ in $A_0$ there exist a $r_a$ with $D_{r_a}(a)\cap B = \emptyset$. After fixing $\delta_a$ by $\mathrm{min}\{ \delta_a, r_a \}$, you can now choose $V_1$ and $U_1$ like before and $V = V_0 \cup V_1$,$U = U_0 \cup U_1$ are disjoint open neighbourhoods of $A$ and $B$. Strictly speaking, choose $U_1$ being an open neighbourhood of $B_1$ with $\overline U_1\cap \mathbb{M}_0 =\emptyset$ (this could be done since $\mathbb{M}_1$ is normal as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and since $\mathbb{M}_1$ is a open neighbourhood of $B_1$, there exist a $V_1$ such that $B\subset V_1 \subset\overline V_1\subset \mathbb{M}_1$), then fix $\delta_a$ for every $a$ such that $D_{r_a}(a)\cap U_1 = \emptyset$.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the time that you've spent on this. However there seem to be gaps in the part of the proof you have provided, and it lends little help to the part you say would be handled by "similar" arguments. I wonder if you spent any time going through details. (continued)

Comment: For an example of a gap in the outlined part, suppose that $A = \{ (1,0) \}$ and $B = \{ (0,1) \}$. In this case $A_1 = \varnothing$ and $B_1 = \{ (0,1) \}$, so one possible separation of these sets in $\mathbb M_1$ is $V_1 = \emptyset$ and $U_1 = \mathbb M_1$. However we then have a major problem coming up with an open neighborhood of $(1,0) \in A$ which is disjoint from $U_1$. (Of course there are other better choices of $U_1$ and $V_1$.) (continued)

Comment: This case can be fixed by being careful about the various neighborhoods chosen however, and I think I'll edit the question to indicate how this can be done. In my view the other case, when $\star \in A \cup B$, is tremendously different, and cannot be simply handled "similarly". At least I don't see it. (continued)

Comment: Even simply taking $A = \{ \star \}$ leads to problems, owning largely to the fact that the open set $V \supseteq A$ must contain uncountably many points of $\mathbb M_0$ arranged in such a way that each $\mathbf u \in B$ can be separated from it. For $\mathbf u \in B \cap \mathbb M_0$ I can arrange this, but am cluelss about points in $B \cap \mathbb M_1$.

Comment: True, I've found a typo in my answer, where I wrote a A rather than B. Now I've corrected this and given some details about case 2. Any comments welcomed. Thx for your patience.

Comment: Thanks for this extension! In your work in the second case, are you assuming that $A_0 = \mathbb M_0 \setminus B_0$? (Recalling that to get a neighborhood of $\star$ we need to include cofinitely many points from $\mathbb M_0$.) I am reacting as though this is the case. (continued)

Comment: With this reading I guess $V_0$ should be $\{ \star \} \cup \bigcup_{a \in A_0} D_{\delta_a} (a)$ (where $\delta_a$ is adjusted as in the final paragraph). But in order to ensure that $V_0$ and $U_1$ are disjoint, we will require that $\overline{V_0}$ is disjoint from $B$, and since there are infinitely many points in $A_0$, simply ensuring that each $\overline{D_{\delta_a}(a)}$ is disjoint from $B$ is not enough. How would this be achieved?

Comment: Have you thought about my comments at all? The bounty will be ending before long, and as it stands I'm not comfortable awarding it to this answer. I don't want to have wasted the reputation into a black hole, but I cannot in good conscience award an answer I am not content with.